# Rsync shows files being copied, but the destination directory doesn't have the files

Tags: rsync, freenas

I put a new drive in my NAS(Freenas) and need to copy the contents from another drive.
I'm signed in as root via SSH. I've been using the command  `rsync -avP  /mnt/Red3TB/Temp/Videos/ /mnt/Red4TB/Temp/Vidoes`

The screen shows files being copied successfully, but when I go to the destination folder in the mapped shared drive in Windows and as root in Putty there are no files there. If I run Rsync again, it starts at the same 1st file. So, I know the files aren't being copied. If they were Rsync would start after the most recent file that was on both source and destination.

I did notice it would say this after I hit Ctrl-C to stop the Rsync

```
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(642) 
[sender=3.1.3]
rsync: mkstemp "/mnt/Red4TB/Temp/Videos/FILENAME_HERE.2Gs8hT" failed: 
Operation not permitted (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like rysnc no longer works with windows datasets and you can't use the -p argument with them. 
These arguments should not be used.
  -a, --archive   equals -rlptgoD (no -H, -A -X)
  -p, --perms     Preserve permssions
  -A, --acls     Preserve ACLs (implies -p)

See [here](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/impaired-rsync-permissions-support-for-windows-datasets.43973/) for full details and credit where I found the answer

Comment: What do you mean by Windows datasets? I would guess that the problem is caused by the Windows **file system** (NTFS, FAT32 or exFAT), where the file permissions cannot be treated individually, when opened in linux. Or is it caused by Windows style **file names** that are not compatible with linux file systems or something else?